# Caused by android.view.InflateException Binary XML file line #101: Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: android, bundle

Got this error from Crashlytics, affecting a few devices:

**Caused by android.view.InflateException
Binary XML file line #101: Binary XML file line #101: Error inflating class**

**Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException
Drawable (missing name) with resource ID #0x7f06008a**

The interesting thing is that this has only come about since I released the app in the new Android App Bundle. This didn't happen when releasing the .apk. In fact to resolve it I reverted back to release it as .apk. But I want to have the benefits of a release with the new Android App Bundle. I know it's something to do with the Drawable folders. Here's line 101 in the xml file:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/learn_chords_help_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/help"
    android:contentDescription="Learn Chords Help"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/learn_chords_button"
    android:layout_above="@id/creditText"
    />
```

Here's all my drawable folders with/without help.png:

```
drawable -> help.png
drawable-hdpi -> help.png
drawable-nodpi -> No Help image
drawable-xhdpi -> No Help image
drawable-xxhdpi -> help.png
```

Here's some devices that the error occurred on (according to Crashlytics, I couldn't replicate it with the few test handsets we have): Galaxy J7(2016) 7.0, Optimus L40 4.42, m3 Note 5.1, Galaxy s4 4.4.2)

Is this a bug in the Google Play's new App Bundle format, or do developers need to have all the drawable folders with assets in each of them?

Comment: did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you don't have `help.png` in `xhdpi` folder, that's why you have that error, because `xhdpi` is associated for `720 X 1280px` density (ex: Galaxy J7).

You could put only the `xxhdpi` picture to `no-dpi` folder, or put that picture in all the folders.

Comment: Interesting point about putting the image in all the folders. This will presumably mean including a drawable-xxxhdpi as well? Why didn't I need to do this with .apk and why now with the new Google App Bundles?

Comment: I think now Google mange better the apks. When you add an image using `Image asset`, it will put it automatically in all the folders. You should use that, not manually. Right click on android package from left navigator -> New -> `Image asset` or `Vector asset` if you have a `SVG` file.

Comment: what if I have this png image in just drawable folder, it should work...

Comment: on crashlytics it happened for Nexus 5x 8.1 Android. I created the same emulator, downloaded the app using app store, but it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

In your build.gradle file of App Level

this may be present

```
bundle {
    density {
        enableSplit true
    }
    abi {
        enableSplit true
    }
    language {
        enableSplit false
    }
}
```

You can remove the `density` tag, or remove the whole bundle tag because this comes in the Beta Release of the AAB, now google will take care of all the resources to split.